# Integrate with square root

Tags: integration

I'm stuck and would need some help to be able to continue.

$\int \frac{1 + \sqrt{x+1}}{1 -1 \sqrt{x+1}} dx = \int \frac{1+t}{1-t}\times2\sqrt{t^2-1+1} dt = t^2\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right) - \int t^2 \frac{2}{(t-1)^2} = \frac{t^2+t^3}{1-t} - 2t - \frac{2}{1-t} - 4 ln  (t-1) + C$

Comment: Undo the change of variable...

Answer (score 0):

my solution:
$$\int\frac{1+\sqrt{x+1}}{1-\sqrt{x+1}}dx\\
=-\int\frac{(1+\sqrt{x+1})^2}{x}dx\\
=-\int\frac{x+2\sqrt{x+1}+2}{x}dx\\
=-\int dx-2\int\frac{dx}{x}-2\int\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{x}dx\\
=-x-2\ln x-2(2\sqrt{x+1}+\ln\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{\sqrt{x+1}+1})\\
=-x-2\ln x-4\sqrt{x+1}-2\ln\frac{(\sqrt{x+1}-1)^2}{x}\\
=-x-4\sqrt{x+1}-2\ln(\sqrt{x-1}+1)^2\\
=-x-4\sqrt{x+1}-4\ln(\sqrt{x-1}+1)$$